# How to draw three squares over lapping each other?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am wanting to draw three overlapping squares in Python using the turtle function similar to this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhfq2.png

So far this is my code

```
    from turtle import *


    # Set up canvas
    setup()
    title('three (3) squares of different colours') 
    speed('fastest') 
    pensize(4)

    # Draw the outline of square
    penup ()
    goto (0,0)
    pendown ()
    color ('black')

    for number in range (4):
    forward(150)
    left(90)
    penup()     

    # Fill square with colour
    goto (0,0)
    color('black', 'yellow')
    pendown()
    begin_fill()

    for number in range (4):
       forward(150)
       left(90)
       end_fill()


    hideturtle ()
    done ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than draw three squares, you've drawn the same square twice -- once filled, once not.  You should be able to draw this figure with a series of simple `forward()`, `right(90)` and `left(90)` commands.  Along with color changes and fill requests.

I think the interesting way to approach it, is to consider that the red and green squares are the same size, so we should be able to reuse the same code with just a different fill color.  A secondary challenge would be, after initially placing the pen optimally in the window, is to draw the figure *without* lifting the pen again.  This is similar to drawing this figure on paper with lifting your pencil.

```
from turtle import *

LENGTH = 415
OUTLINE = 10

title('Three (3) squares of different colours')

pensize(OUTLINE)

penup()
goto(-LENGTH/4, LENGTH/4)  # center drawing on the window
pendown()

fillcolor('lime')

for _ in range(2):
    begin_fill()

    forward(LENGTH/2)
    right(90)

    for _ in range(3):
        forward(LENGTH)
        right(90)

    forward(LENGTH/2)

    end_fill()

    fillcolor('red')
    left(90)

left(90)
fillcolor('yellow')
begin_fill()

for _ in range(4):
    forward(LENGTH/2)
    left(90)

end_fill()

hideturtle()
exitonclick()
```

Just some ideas.  There are other fun ways to approach this drawing.  For example, instead of *drawing*, we could use *stamping*:

```
from turtle import *

LENGTH = 415
OUTLINE = 10
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

title('Three (3) squares of different colours')

penup()
shape('square')
shapesize(LENGTH / CURSOR_SIZE, outline=OUTLINE)

goto(LENGTH/4, LENGTH/4)
fillcolor('red')
stamp()

goto(-LENGTH/4, -LENGTH/4)
fillcolor('lime')
stamp()

shapesize(LENGTH / 2 / CURSOR_SIZE)
home()
fillcolor('yellow')
stamp()

hideturtle()
exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a go :)

Comment: instead of thanking & deleting the question & the answer, consider testing the answer, and accept it if you find it useful.